# how to generate all possible equations with a set of number and operators?

Tags: algorithm

I got a maths and programming problem.

For given that a set of character `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,*,/}`. And then by using the set of characters to randomly generate `10` (or let say `N`) characters in an array, i.e. `[1,+,1,∗,3,5,7,8,1]`. After that I need to find all the possibility of equations by using this array of characters plus 1 character '='.

Therefore in this case, `[1,+,1,∗,3,5,7,8,1]` it would be like the following equations: `1*1=1` , `3+5=8` ,  `7+1=8` ,  `15=8+7` , `15+3=18` (maybe more)

It can form multiple digit operation, i.e `15+3=18`

so my question is I am trying using a program to generate the equations all. Could you guys give me some ideas what kind of algorithms can do so? or any methods do it?

**my current approach:**

my approach is not fast enough. so the idea is, the minimum equation needs 3 number and 1 operator. and

1. i start from randomly pick 4 members from the generated array. if these 4 members have one operator,
2. then i would add the '='
3. form all the possible orders . e.g. 1,1,2,+ , i will have 112+=, 121+= ,1=12+ .... loop through all that. and
4. then increase to 5 members and loop through it...
5. do it until the length of array generated

Comment: "it can form multiple digit operation, i.e 15+3=18" - then you have infinitely many equations.

Comment: Seeing how you have to solve the subset sum problem as part of this, we can at least assume that your problem is NP-complete. Regarding a structured approach to generating all equations: what have you got so far.

Comment: @H2CO3 For a finite multiset of digits, he doesn't. The number of equations is at most exponential in the number of available digits/numbers, because the number of permutations is bounded by n^n.

Comment: @H2CO3, it wont be infinitely, can you imagine some small set like if the array is just [1,2,3,+]; it would be only 1+2=3

Comment: @G.Bach `1 + 1 = 2; 1 + 11 = 12; 1 + 111 = 112;` etc., can you not continue this ad infinitum?

Comment: @H2CO3 Since he gives a multiset with multiple occurrences of `1` as an example, I would assume that you can use every element of the multiset at most as often as it occurs in the multiset.

Comment: it is depending on the array generated. please read the question carefully.

Comment: Generate all permutations of all subsets of the characters. Parse and evaluate the equations and keep those where the equality holds. While it is running, do something else.

Comment: I don't think it's infinite, I think it's ((N! * N) - 1) * 4 ... that's a rough guess, still an awful lot of possibilities to test individually.

Comment: @AndersForsgren Just computing the permutations of the array doesn't suffice, he'll also have to do that for subsets.

Comment: Yes "all permutations of all subsets", surely that must be all possible equations?

Comment: @G.Bach, just skip the explanation. my approach is not fast enough. so the idea is, the minimum equation needs 3 number and 1 operator. and i start from randomly pick 4 members from the generated array.  if these 4 members have one operator, then i would add the '=' to form all the possible orders . e.g. 1,1,2,+ , i will have 112+=, 121+= ,1=12+ .... loop through all that. and then increase to 5 members and loop through it... do it until the length of array generated.

Comment: do you guys have faster way to do it ?

Comment: @justicepenny Please add some code to your answer. Also, randomly picking stuff from the array seems like an odd way to approach it.

Comment: Put what you have tried so far in the question.

Comment: code is not yet written.. just the seudo algoritm.

Comment: you guys know what if I have an generated array with 20 , only one case, the number of combination of picking 4 in this 20 is 20Cr4 =20!/(20-4)!*4! so it is 4845 combinations. and in each of the combination i need to loop 5!. that why i ask if there is some kind of faster solution for that?

Comment: @justicepenny If you read my first post, you will realize that no one can give you something sub-exponential since no one knows how to solve subset-sum faster than in exponential time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @G.Bach . I will post my code once I have done. thanks. btw I have no single clue why so many stupid people closed my question. I am really fed up with those kind of arrogant and stupid people who doesnt understand the question and find it off the topic ..

Comment: @justicepenny I have **no idea** why someone would vote to close this as **off topic**, much less 3-5 people, because it clearly relates directly to programming. However, some may consider it **not a real question** (I would point you to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close), but it doesn't really say much - basically, in this context, it means you didn't show enough of an attempt at solving the problem yourself). Though I'm somewhat on the fence here, so I won't vote to close or reopen, but I'm happy to answer it, as I did, as I deem interesting and challenging enough.

Comment: well I did reply my approach on the above comments. Why dont i put my approach in my question , because i found so many people do that just for the sake of these kind of stupid people and showing them what they did try. However, my point of view is I dont wanna confuse and provide them unnecessary information. That's why I try to be seudo code and explain it , instead of using exact coding. But you know there is so many haters. stupidity and arrogance make them think that if something that dont know, then it is not worth to answer. just feel sorry for stackoverflow having them here.

Comment: @justicepenny [so] questions should (generally) show what you have tried. This is simply the way it is. It doesn't have to be code or even pseudo-code, it can just be a few sentences explaining what you tried or what you thought of. Many people will point you [here](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (if they haven't already), which you should give an open-minded read. I mean no offence by this, but if you're not happy with the way it works on [so], you should probably find a different site, because you're more likely to find resistance than anything else in attempting to change it.

Comment: that's no problem for me to give what i have tried. just read on my above comments. I did write my approach. but the thing is they still not happy with that. What can I do? and these people have such a power to close my question that make me not quite happy, and the reason that they closed my question is off topic, WTF is that mean? And I am not asking for code as well, just an algorithm or an idea to solve in a smarter way. I do have open minded in this case, but seems to me that some people here are not open minded to people question.

Comment: my bad , corrected already! thanks for your remind

Comment: @justicepenny Did you address glh's second equation? Do you allow operators on both the left hand side and the right hand side like `7+1=3+5`?

Comment: no, if the random generated array has no two '+'s then you cant use it, in this case [1,+,1,∗,3,5,7,8,1] has only 1 '+'

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments, this appears to be NP-complete, thus exponential, thus it will take **really** long, but here's what I'd do nonetheless:

For each possible subset A of the input do the following:

Generate all permutations of A.

So each permutation corresponds to an equation (or that thing that's like an equation but **doesn't have an `=` sign**).

Now note that there's going to be a lot of invalid 'equation's. Things like `1**1`. You need to ignore all of these as you go. Roughly anything starting or ending with an operator or with 2 operators in a row is invalid (or maybe not, `1*-2`, `-2+1` and `1--1` (?) is valid (what about `1++1` and `+1+2`?), but anyway, I'm sure you can figure something out).

For each valid permutation, add the number resulting from evaluating it to a set (well, a (multi-)map of number to equation).

Do the same for all permutations of remaining items when A has been removed from the input (resulting in another generated set).

Now all numbers that appear in both sets are valid equations. Note that (for a lack of desire to explain) you'll do a [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join)-like process on all equations that have the same number.

Did we just generate each set twice, once on the left, once on the right? Whoops. Ok, here's a fix: "Pick any element, for each possible subset A of the input containing that element...".

**Something to think about - separating out the operators**

**Advantage:** It may be a lot faster (not really sure, it may even be slower)
**Disadvantage:** It's a lot more complex

Pre-process the input, removing all operators and simply have a count for each operator.

Do exactly the same as above, but, for each permutation, also generate all permutations of where the operators can go. If done right, you should be able to completely avoid invalid equations.

And also have multiple sets to put the numbers into (so you'll have 2 sets of sets), one for each possible amount of each type of operators allowed, which you'll then compare against another set (in the other set of sets) such that the number of operators are all used.

To explain with an example:

Input: `[1,*,1,3,5,7,8,+,+,1]`

Input without operators: `[1,1,3,5,7,8,1]`

Operators:

```
Operator  Count
+         2
*         1
```

An example subset: `[1,7,8,1]`
Its complement: `[1,3,5]`

Now we'll have 2x 6 sets, one for each combination of possible operators for both sets:

```
            ++*      ++      +*      +      *      NONE
Subset      +1*1+78  11+7+8  1*1+78  117+8  1*178  1178
Complement  +3*5+1   3+5+1   3*5+1   35+1   3*51   351
```

The above are just examples, there are obviously a lot more than 1 equation going into each set, you need to consider everywhere the operators can go, for example, considering `++*`:

```
+1+1*78
+1+17*8
+11+7*8
1+1+7*8
1*1+7+8
1+1*7+8
etc.
```

And I just considered the permutation `1178` of the example and `351` of the complement, but all permutations will need to be added (i.e. 1187, 1718, 1781, ... and 315, 513, 531, ...).

Once all of these are added to the sets, you match up the sets as follows, so we use all the operators in an equation:

```
Subset      Complement
++*    with NONE
++     with *
+*     with +
+      with +*
*      with ++
NONE   with ++*
```

To give some better idea of what happens, and assuming we're really bad at maths, we can say: (taken from the above grid)

```
+1*1+78 = 351
11+7+8 = 3*51
1*1+78 = 35+1
etc.
```

Now you'll match the equations up using the value it evaluates to (using sorted sets will allow you to step through both at the same time in linear time). So, let's say equation A and B of the subset both evaluate to 79, and equation C and D of the complement also evaluate to 79. Now you'll match them up as follows: (this is what I meant by CROSS JOIN)

```
A = C
A = D
B = C
B = D
```

and also (if you want these):

```
C = A
C = B
D = A
D = B
```

I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort. I think your second idea is cool! but i dont really understand your last paragraph reason for the second idea. Could you please explain a bit more detailed. thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for the effort - I honestly didn't read it all but there should be enough useful thoughts in there to get justicepenny going.

Comment: @Dukeling really thanks a lot for your help!!! I would try to implement it and let you know the result

Answer (score 0):

As a raw hack at the solution using your example set above one algorithm would be the straightforward find all the combinations of the selected numbers, operators and = and test e.g.

- All 9 plus the = (10 characters) in all variations. Number of would be `10×9×8×7×6×5×4×3×2×1 = 10! = 3,628,800` variations.
- Then 8 plus the = (9 characters) in all variations.  `10×9×8×7×6×5×4×3×2 = 10!÷1!`.
- Then 7 plus the = (8 characters) in all variations.  `10×9×8×7×6×5×4×3 = 10!÷2!`.
- Etc until 4 plus the = (3 numbers and 2 operators = 5 characters) in all variations.  `10×9×8×7×6 = 10!÷5!`.

This equation is then `(n+1)!÷0! + (n+1)!÷1! + ... + (n+1)!÷(n-4)!`

- Where `n` is the number of generated numbers and operators minus the =.

In your example there will be **9,858,240** potential equations. It is of note there will be invalid equations where the = is at the ends, = and an operator together etc. So I'm positive a better one can exist.

- Excluding the = being on the ends will reduce this by 1,971,648